# Binary Insertion Sort Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Looking at this example from geek for geeks in python, (only binary search definition is shown here) I don’t understand the first if/else statement.  Is this accounting for the case where “start, end” boundaries of BS are equal and determining whether we insert to the left or right I’m this case? If so, it’s not clear from the code comments why. Thanks

```
def binary_search(arr, val, start, end): 
    # we need to distinugish whether we should insert 
    # before or after the left boundary. 
    # imagine [0] is the last step of the binary search 
    # and we need to decide where to insert -1 
    if start == end: 
        if arr[start] > val: 
            return start 
        else: 
            return start+1

    # this occurs if we are moving beyond left's boundary 
    # meaning the left boundary is the least position to 
    # find a number greater than val 
    if start > end: 
        return start 

    mid = (start+end)/2
    if arr[mid] < val: 
        return binary_search(arr, val, mid+1, end) 
    elif arr[mid] > val: 
        return binary_search(arr, val, start, mid-1) 
    else: 
        return mid
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, the midpoint and start/end will converge (both the same).

If they were the same, we could just return the midpoiit. When we run `binary_search(MID+1, END)`, since they are equal midpoint is now greater than end. In this case, we return the first parameter

Comment: well if you have start=6 and end=5, its going to cause some issues.

Comment: So this simply returning the v mid point value, start in this case?